# Push changes to remote repo without including latest local commit

Tags: git, github

My local git repo is 1 commit ahead of my remote one. I don't wanna push the latest local commit but I wanna make a small change on the remote repo. What can I do in this case?

Comment: The normal way to update something on a remote repo, is to update it on a local repo and push it out to the remote. You could use separate branches locally so you can push one change to the remote without the other.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I removed last commit without deleting changes. Using:

> $ git reset --soft HEAD~1

Stashed the changes.

Made the small change I wanted and pushed.

Then I popped the stash and commited again.

Comment: What does "went back 1 commit" mean?

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).